# Number of observation as a share of total observations per year

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data frame in R:

```
    Year   ID
1   2018   x
2   2018   x
3   2018   y
4   2018   z
5   2019   x
6   2019   x
7   2019   z
```

and I want to calculate the share of 'x' of the total observations in the column 'ID' separately for each year.

The outcome should look like this:

```
Year   Share of x
2018   50 %
2019   67 %
```

Is it possible to do it with `aggregate`, somehow like this:

```
aggregate(length(which(df$ID == x)) / length(df$ID), by=Year)
```

or any other functions?

Comment: `aggregate(ID ~ Year, df, function(x) mean(x == 'x'))`. The mean value of a logical (coded as 0/1) returns the proportions of successes. Also, the same principle applies to `length(which(condition))` and `sum(condition)`.

Comment: This was a really fast and simple way to do what I wanted. Thank you for that @Rui.
What if I, additionally to _year_, want to add another variable, by which to group? For example _month_
Would it be possible to use aggregate somehow like this: `aggregate(ID ~ Year ~ Month, df, function(x) mean(x == 'x'))` ?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic

Comment: The formula then would be `ID ~ Year + Month`. See the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) of model formulae in R.

Comment: Thank you again @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to do it like this

```
dfout<- setNames(aggregate(ID~Year,df,function(v) sum(v=="x")/length(v)*100),
                 c("Year","Share of x"))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Year Share of x
1 2018   50.00000
2 2019   66.66667
```

**DATA**

```
df <-structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L), ID = c("x", "x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas!

Would it be possible to add another variable by which to group, for example _month_:
`setNames(aggregate(ID~Year~Month,df,function(v) sum(v=="x")/length(v)*100),
                 c("Year","Share of x"))`
?

Comment: @Falcc I guess what you mean might be `ID~Year + Month`, i.e., grouping by `Year` and `Month`, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `table` to compute the counts and then `prop.table` to calculate each as a proportion of its row.

```
prop.table(table(dat), 1)
##       ID
## Year           x         y         z
##   2018 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.2500000
##   2019 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.3333333
```

or if you want the proportion of each column:

```
prop.table(table(dat), 2)
##       ID
## Year     x   y   z
##   2018 0.5 1.0 0.5
##   2019 0.5 0.0 0.5
```

### aggregate

Regarding the `aggregate` tag on the question the first case could be done like this:

```
aggregate(ID ~ Year, dat, 
  function(id) sapply(unique(dat$ID), function(x) setNames(mean(id == x), x)))
##   Year      ID.x      ID.y      ID.z
## 1 2018 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.2500000
## 2 2019 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.3333333
```

or using both `aggregate` and `table`:

```
aggregate(ID ~ Year, dat, function(x) table(x) / length(x))
##   Year      ID.x ID.y      ID.z
## 1 2018 0.5000000 0.25 0.2500000
## 2 2019 0.6666667 0.00 0.3333333
```

### dplyr / tidyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  count(Year, ID) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  pivot_wider(-n, names_from = "ID", values_from = "prop", values_fill = list(prop = 0))

## # A tibble: 2 x 4
## # Groups:   Year [2]
##    Year     x     y     z
##   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1  2018 0.5    0.25 0.25 
## 2  2019 0.667  0    0.333
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "    Year   ID
1   2018   x
2   2018   x
3   2018   y
4   2018   z
5   2019   x
6   2019   x
7   2019   z     "
dat <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

data<- tribble(~year,~id,
               2018,"x",
               2018,"x",
               2018,"y",
               2018,"z",
               2019,"x",
               2019,"x",
               2019,"z"

)


agg <- data %>% group_by(year,id) %>% 
            summarise(cnt_id = n()) %>% # count id per year
            group_by(year) %>% 
            mutate(cnt_obs = sum(cnt_id),#count total obs per year
                   share = cnt_id/cnt_obs) %>% 
                    filter(id=="x") %>% 
                    select(year,id,share)
head(agg)
   year id    share
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1  2018 x     0.5  
2  2019 x     0.667
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that 2019y is missing but still

```
library(tidyverse)

df<- tribble(~year,~id,
               2018,"x",
               2018,"x",
               2018,"y",
               2018,"z",
               2019,"x",
               2019,"x",
               2019,"z"

)

df %>% 
  group_by(year,id) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id,values_from = prop) %>% 
  mutate_all(~ replace_na(.,replace = 0))
```